# How to run index.html outside the dist folder using webpack devserver

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Apart from the dist folder, I have another folder called dev. And this dev folder contains the index.html file.

I am connecting index.html file with the css and js file which is available in dist folder.

Folder structure:

```
|-- dev
  |-- index.html

|-- dist
  |-- scroll.carousel.js
  |-- scroll.carousel.css

|-- src 
  |-- js
    |-- index.js
    |-- other.js
  |-- scss
    |-- style.scss
```

Index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/scroll.carousel.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>


  <script src="../dist/scroll.carousel.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**My problem:**

1. When i run dev server i can't get css styles.
2. My dev server does not refresh automatically

I want to refresh the browser every time I make a change in the src folder.

**My webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin = require('webpack-remove-empty-scripts');



module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  target: 'web',
  entry: {
    ["scroll.carousel"]: './src/js/index.js',
    ["scroll.carousel.style"]: './src/scss/style.scss',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: "/",
    clean: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: (pathData) => {
        if (pathData.chunk.name.includes(".style")) {
          return pathData.chunk.name.replace(".style", "") + ".css"
        }
        return '[name].css'
      },
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Extract CSS
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              url: false
            }
          },
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dev'),
      watch: true,
    },
    watchFiles: ["./src/**/*"],
    open: true,
    liveReload: true
  },  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clarification

### First of all, I'm curious whether your folder structure is *intentional* or just an honest beginner mistake. I'm going to **assume the latter**.

1. **Answer** Problem 1 (*When i run dev server i can't get css styles*)
   First of all, how do you load html? I don't see any [**HtmlWebpackPlugin**](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) or layoutloader. Your dist folder (*the output folder generated **only when** you build*) should include index.html file optimized for production. For now, it is obvious your index.html file should be in the **/src**. For styles to load, you need styleloader first [See here](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/). Then import your main .scss file into your index.js file, webpack will load your css automatically.

---

2. **Answer** Problem 2 (*My dev server does not refresh automatically*)
   `watch: true` can be omitted, it's enabled by default. Try changing `entry: { ["scroll.carousel"]: './src/js/index.js', ["scroll.carousel.style"]: './src/scss/style.scss', }` **to** `entry: { main: './src/js/index.js' },`.  Also, trying changing `directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dev')` **to** `directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dev')`.

---

For more about webpack config [See here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/)

Comment: My folder structure is intentionally like this. But i am new to webpack. For your first answer: May be you get me wrong. I have html file in dev folder. Dist folder should not contain any html file. Because i am making a library. And for that htmlwebpackplugin is not necessary here. By the way, i have solved it. It was the problem for publicPath property

Comment: Yes, I also had the same problem of publicPath when i got started. Did you use publicPath: ASSET_PATH ? Thank you for clarifying.